# How to conditionally build a list in a for loop in python

Tags: python, list

How could I make `sequence_C` with the values after the if print as one list like `sequence`

```
sequence=["A","C","G","T","T","A","G","C","T","A","A","C","G"]
for i in sequence:
    sequence_C=[]
    if i=="A":
        sequence_C.append("T")
    elif i=="T":
        sequence_C.append("A")
    elif i=="C":
        sequence_C.append("G")
    else:
        sequence_C.append("C")
    print(sequence_C)
```

Comment: Don't print `sequence_C` until *after* the loop. Also, don't reinitialize `sequence_C` every time the loop iterates.

Comment: Easier to do via a comprehension, e.g. `sequence_C = [dict(("AT", "TA", "CG", "GC"))[i] for i in sequence]`.

Answer (score 1):

Only initialise `sequence_C` once, before the loop starts.

```
sequence_C = []
for i in sequence:
    if i=="A":
        sequence_C.append("T")
    elif i=="T":
        sequence_C.append("A")
    elif i=="C":
        sequence_C.append("G")
    else:
        sequence_C.append("C")
print(sequence_C)
```

You can more easily solve this using a dictionary and a list comprehension, like so:

```
mapping = {'T': 'A', 'A': 'T', 'G': 'C', 'C': 'G'}
sequence_C = [mapping[item] for item in sequence]
```

There's a lot less duplicated code like this!

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that should happen to `sequence_C` *inside* the loop is to have values appended to it. Do not initialize it to `[]` in the loop, and do not print the value of `sequence_C` in the loop.

```
sequence=["A","C","G","T","T","A","G","C","T","A","A","C","G"]

sequence_C = []

for i in sequence:
    if i=="A":
        sequence_C.append("T")
    elif i=="T":
        sequence_C.append("A")
    elif i=="C":
        sequence_C.append("G")
    else:
        sequence_C.append("C")

print(sequence_C)
```

The simplest thing to do, though, is to create a translation table.

```
sequence = "ACGTTAGCTAACG"
sequence_C = sequence.translate(str.maketrans("ATCG", "TAGC"))
```

Comment: The original code maps everything but TAG to C, whereas `translate` doesn't do that.  This may be a reasonable thing to do, but OP should clarify that there can't be anything but those 4 characters.

Comment: The OP is clearly operating on DNA nucleobases, in which case a value of `sequence` containing anything other than `A`s, `T`s, `C`s, or `G`s is a domain error. I think it's safe to assume that mapping any other character to itself or `C` is equally wrong.

Comment: Um, I was just pointing out how your code differs from the original. That may not be obvious to future readers.

Answer (score 0):

You create a new list on each run of the loop. Pull that out to keep appending to a single list.

```
sequence=["A","C","G","T","T","A","G","C","T","A","A","C","G"]
sequence_C=[]
for i in sequence:
    if i=="A":
        sequence_C.append("T")
    elif i=="T":
        sequence_C.append("A")
    elif i=="C":
        sequence_C.append("G")
    else:
        sequence_C.append("C")
print(sequence_C)
```

But there is a better way. Dictionaries map one one value to another. Use that instead.

```
s_map = {"A":"T", "T":"A", "C":"G"} # w/ default "C"
sequence_C = [s_map.get(s, "C") for s in sequence]
print(sequence_C)
```